# What was the root cause for the recent (March 2017) Struts2 file upload vulnerability (S2-045)?

Tags: code-execution

The recent Struts2 vulnerability allowed remote code execution by providing a bogus Content-Type header, as explained here:
https://threatprotect.qualys.com/2017/03/08/apache-struts-jakarta-multipart-parser-remote-code-execution-vulnerability/

The page above also links to - what I assume are - the [fixing](https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/352306493971e7d5a756d61780d57a76eb1f519a) [commits](https://github.com/apache/struts/commit/b06dd50af2a3319dd896bf5c2f4972d2b772cf2b). What I have been unable to find so far is where in struts' code base the bogus header was actually evaluated.

The [Struts wiki itself](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-045) states:

> **Problem**
>
> It is possible to perform a RCE attack with a malicious
>   Content-Type value. If the Content-Type value isn't valid an exception
>   is thrown which is then used to display an error message to a user.

But simply passing an error message through, even when composed of user input, shouldn't run an exec() command, surely?

Can anyone explain how this vulnerability actually worked, technically - preferably with a link to the buggy line in Struts' repo? Or is there really no `exec` culprit?